# I upgraded the software on my iPhone and my Yahoo Calendar stopped syncing via CalDav

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, caldav, yahoo

I recently updated my iPhone to IOS 5.0.  I was [syncing my iPhone calendar with my Yahoo Calendar using CalDav](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/calendar/yahoocalendar/sync/sync-01.html).  After the upgrade the syncing stopped working.  I tried deleting the calendar sync profile and re-adding it, but when I get to the step where it verifies the settings, it fails.  What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix the problem.  I got the answer from [this forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16635920#16635920).

1. Delete CalDav Yahoo calendar sync profile in the iPhone settings.
2. Go to Safari settings and click *Clear History* and *Clear Cookies and Data*.
3. Turn iPhone off.
4. Turn iPhone on.
5. Re-add you Yahoo Calendar CalDav account.

To re-add your Yahoo Calendar CalDav account:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. Click *Mail Contacts, Calendars*
3. Click *Add Account Option*
4. Click *Other*
5. Click *Add CalDAV Account*
6. Server: `https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com`
7. Enter you Yahoo user name and password.
8. Click *Save*.